# Importing in Programming

Tags: python, haskell

I've noticed in a lot of examples there are "import ..." as such in Haskell;

```hs
-- file: ch05/PrettyJSON.hs
module PrettyJSON
    (
      renderJValue
    ) where

import Numeric (showHex)
import Data.Char (ord)
import Data.Bits (shiftR, (.&.))

import SimpleJSON (JValue(..))
import Prettify (Doc, (<>), char, double, fsep, hcat, punctuate, text,
                 compact, pretty
```

Do you have to create those import packages or are they already included in the programming language (or computer).

If you don't need to create an import, then where do you get it and can you view the coding?

Comment: some packages are already included with a typical installation, some you can download and install (e.g., with "pip" or other utilities), some you can create yourself. Often these packages are installed into a "site-packages" directory, you can go there and view the python code making up the packages. The specifics depend on your specific system.

Comment: Does this mean I can make my own imports based on mathematical expressions and functions? Thank you for your comment, I'll look into the site-packages directory. Does this also mean I may need to modify some packages based on a different types of projects?

Comment: Yes. Here's is more information: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Comment: I disagree with the close votes arguing that this question is "too broad". The core elements of the answer can be expressed in a few lines of language-agnostic explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Haskell-centric answer:

```hs
import Numeric (showHex)
```

This line imports the `showHex` function within the `Numeric` *module*. Modules are groups of functions, data types and other such things, arranged in a way to allow easy reuse. Some modules come with the basic installation of the compiler, others you can install later on (in Haskell, they are distributed as *packages*, which you can install with tools such as cabal-install), and finally there are those you define for use in your programs. In fact, the snippet you included in your question is the beginning of a module, called `PrettyJSON`, which makes the `renderJValue` function available when you import it elsewhere.

> and can you view the coding?

Most Haskell packages written by other people that you can install are distributed through [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/). By browsing Hackage, you can find documentation for the packages and their modules, as well as read their source code. For instance, [here is the definition of `showHex`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Numeric.html#showHex) in the `Numeric` module. (By the way, `Numeric` is part of the `base` package. `base` comes with the compiler, and so you don't need to install anything else to use it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Python, all the packages are already pre-included.
For example:

```
import statistics
```

or:

```
from statistics import variance
```

and then you can use the function within that package, do check out the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/) for more information on the various packages. This is just a short example:

```
statistics.variance(a)
```

Comment: Of course you can use third-party packages or write your own packages and modules.

Comment: Yes, and they simply consist of .py files with definitions and placed in C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages

Answer (score 0):

Importing packages allows you to leverage the power of these languages in a convenient way. Some packages are modules that come built-in with the language of your choice and some are built by programmers to create added functionality. From the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html):

> Python provides standardized solutions for many problems that occur in everyday programming.

Check out [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#modules) simple example in Python in which you create a `fibo.py file and then import it in your terminal like so:

```
import fibo
print fibo.fib(1000)
```

And perform Fibbonacci evaluations on a range of numbers. I suggest you read over the docs regarding [Modules](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules) and more examples on how to use them, that might help clarify some of your questions.